# strtotime() function in PHP

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I want to calculate the exact time in seconds after a variable number of weeks. I'm using `strtotime()` but I can only get it working with a hard-coded number of weeks. My code:

```
$time = "Monday";  // any day
$weekDifference = 2;  // variable of week difference

$myTime = strtotime("+weekDifference week $time");  // it does not works
// strtotime("+2 week $time ") this works
echo $myTime;   // no value is printed
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the $-sign in the weekDifference variable.

```
 $myTime = strtotime("+$weekDifference week $time");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

$myTime = strtotime("+$weekDifference week $time");

It will work

cheers